# Rendering HTML view for a string with HTML contents  and display it in Webpage/Outlook as HTML using Applescript 

Tags: html, file, macos, formatting, applescript

This applescript takes the HTML contents of an email and stores it in a string and again pastes the html content to `webpage.html`. But, when I open `webpage.html`, it displays all the HTML tags as a text rather than HTML view.

```
set mytext to string
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set the_messages to selection
    repeat with this_message in the_messages
        set mytext to content of this_message
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document
    set text of document 1 to mytext as text
    save document 1 in "/Users/mymac/Desktop/webpage.html"
end tell
```

The problem here is, it pastes the entire HTML as plain text to the `webpage.html`. So the content now appears with all tags. How can I make the webpage appear with HTML formatting using Applescript.

**EDIT:**

I have uploaded the webpage.html file [here](http://www.2shared.com/document/Tcg87ZQ-/webpage.html)

This is the [view](http://www.2shared.com/document/Tcg87ZQ-/webpage.html) which is rendered in the reading pane of the outlook mail window after doing modifications.

```
set mytext to string
set hello to "hello this is testing"
set outputText to string
--get the content of a outlook message
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set the_messages to selection
    repeat with this_message in the_messages
        --set mytext to content of this_message
        set mytext to source of this_message
    end repeat

 --adding some text to the content of the message
    set mytext to mytext & hello
end tell

--pasting the content to a html file 
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    make new document
    set text of document 1 to mytext as text
    --set source of document 1 to mytext as text
    save document 1 in "/Users/mymac/Desktop/webpage.html"
end tell

--reading the contents from the html file
set theFile to "/Users/mymac/Desktop/webpage.html"
open for access theFile
set fileContents to (read theFile)
close access theFile

--pasting the modified contents to the outlook email
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set the_messages to selection
    repeat with this_message in the_messages
        set content of this_message to fileContents --modified email 
        --set fileContents to source of this_message(this does not modify the source of the message in view pane,Remains intact the original source)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Question:

How to view the email as it is sent to the user, even after doing modifications?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?Is my question clear?

Comment: Do you see the text in browser or text editor when you open html file?

Comment: I see the entire page source as HTML in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the **source of webpage.html** file rather than the content of the file. This solved my problem.